# angularjs - on click, how can I handle duplicates in an object in a list where on click, an accordion opens?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I looked at http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz.

Here's what I was trying out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxjpwd

Basically, if my object has duplicates in it, such as Basketball coming up 3 times, how can I make sure that on tap it only opens that particular Basketball entry?

```
    var allGames = {
        "1": "Basketball",
        "2": "Baseball",
        "3": "Basketball",
        "4": "Football",
        "5": "Basketball"
      };
    $scope.games = allGames;

  $scope.toggleGames = function(game) {
    if ($scope.onTapGame(game)) {
      $scope.shown = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shown = game;
    }
  };
  $scope.onTapGame = function(game) {
    return $scope.shown === game;
  };
```

And in my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games">
        <ion-item class="item item-button-right" ng-click="toggleGames(game)" ng-class="{active: onTapGame(game)}">
          {{game}}          
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="onTapGame(game)">

        </ion-item>
      </div>
```

Comment: You are trying to use array methods in view but passing object in scope instead of array. Strongly suggest you convert `allGames` to array of objects instead of one object

Comment: It is a bad idea to compare objects with `===`

Comment: track by $index in the ng-repeat ...

Comment: thanks.  zazu can you please explain why if you dont mind?  thanks trying to learn

Comment: @AskskdRieid because javascript do not compares object by properties, but instead it does by pointers. If you get a clone of the object you simply get false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of working with values that don't have to be unique, work with keys, which have to be unique.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, game) in games">
        <ion-item class="item item-button-right" ng-click="toggleGames(key)" ng-class="{active: onTapGame(key)}">
          {{game}}          
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="onTapGame(key)">

        </ion-item>
 </div>
```

and your AngularJS code:

```
var allGames = {
    "1": "Basketball",
    "2": "Baseball",
    "3": "Basketball",
    "4": "Football",
    "5": "Basketball"
  };
$scope.games = allGames;

$scope.toggleGames = function(key) {
  if ($scope.onTapGame(key)) {
    $scope.shown = null;
  } else {
    $scope.shown = key;
  }
};
$scope.onTapGame = function(key) {
  return $scope.shown === key;
};
```

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZgpWm)

Answer (score 0):

Ng-repeat directive adds a unique identificator under `$ for each object if there are no`track by` is stated in the expression. So to be sure you work with object you need you can change your code to:

```
$scope.toggleGames = function(game) {
    if ($scope.onTapGame(game)) {
      $scope.shown = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shown = game.$$hashKey;
    }
  };
  $scope.onTapGame = function(game) {
    return $scope.shown === game.$$hashKey;
  };
```